# How to use a ReactJS Component with Clojurescipt/Reagent

Tags: reactjs, clojurescript, reagent

Is it possible to wrap ReactJS components for use with [Reagent](https://holmsand.github.io/reagent/) in Clojurescript? I have [read](https://holmsand.github.io/reagent/news/any-arguments.html) that it is. Can someone provide me with a basic example?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Here is my solution for it (I am going to use a [React-Bootstrap Panel](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#panels) Component):

1) Include `react-bootstrap.min.js` in your html.

2) Here is a sample usage of the Panel component:

```
(def PanelComp (. js/ReactBootstrap -Panel))
(defn page
  []
  [:div
   [:div [PanelComp {:header "Panel heading without title"} "Panel content"]]])
```

Comment: Reagent 0.5.0 added a new way of doing this using `adapt-react-class`. I've got a sample use [here](https://gist.github.com/ducky427/10551a3346695db6a5f0)