# How to prepare a React.js component for usage in ClojureScript as an external Reagent component?

Tags: reactjs, clojurescript, reagent

I would like to use this React.js component as a foreign Reagent component in a ClojureScript application :

https://github.com/felixrieseberg/React-Spreadsheet-Component.

This component is however not available in the repository:

http://cljsjs.github.io/.

If a React.js component is available in the directory then using it with Reagent would be as simple as in the following example.

```
(ns demo.views
  (:require [reagent.core :as reagent]
            [cljsjs.reactable]])

(defn example []
  [:div
  [:> Reactable.Table
    {:data (clj->js [
                 {:name "Foo" :section 51}
                 {:name "Bar" :section 51}
                 ])}
    ]
   ]
  )
```

I would like to know what I would have to do with the React Spreadsheet Component such that I can use it in a similar simple way. How to prepare a React.js component for usage in ClojureScript as an external Reagent component? Please provide a clear recipe type of description.

Note: This question [How to use a ReactJS Component with Clojurescipt/Reagent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27110425/how-to-use-a-reactjs-component-with-clojurescipt-reagent) looks similar but does not answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It boils down to how you want to do JavaScript interop... you have 3 choices:

1. Include the js from your HTML file
2. Build it as part of your compilation
3. Include it as a library

I encourage you to try (3); it isn't difficult, just follow the steps on CLJSJS https://github.com/cljsjs/packages/wiki/Creating-Packages

Comment: Are you saying that with all three options I can use it as a an external Reagent component? I thought that was only possible with option 3. As for option 3, I looked at that description, of course, I find step 4 a really difficult one.

Comment: For step 4 you can use a generator like http://www.dotnetwise.com/Code/Externs/index.html so you don't need to do externs by hand.

Comment: Now that really helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use [ClojureScript's compiler options](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Compiler-Options#foreign-libs) to include the external JS in the build, then use reagent's [`adapt-react-class`](http://blog.ducky.io/reagent-docs/0.5.1/reagent.core.html#var-adapt-react-class) to use the component in your reagent views. Try not to depend on projects like CLJSJS.

Doing this yourself will keep you in control of your project.

in `project.clj`

```
:foreign-libs [{:file "https://rawgit.com/felixrieseberg/React-Spreadsheet-Component/master/dist/spreadsheet.js"
                :provides  ["no-idea"]}]
```

in the views

```
(def reactable-table (r/adapt-react-class js/Reactable.Table))

(defn example []
  [:div
  [reactable-table
    {:data (clj->js [
                 {:name "Foo" :section 51}
                 {:name "Bar" :section 51}])}]])
```

Note however that this component bundles lots of dependencies (jQuery). You might be better of by making a component like this yourself, in clojurescript/reagent.

Comment: It comes to down to making an :externs file right? The point is that I haven't got a clue how to create such a file.